# Want Images as PanoramaItems in WP7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a `Panorama` control where i need to programmaticaly add items which are images.
I want to implement them so that flicking on the image slide to second image and so on..
I did add images to the panaroma item but it always shows one image only.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
     image_new = new Image();
     PanoramaItem pi = new PanoramaItem();

     image_new.Source = "Some image Bitmap";
     pi.Content = image_new;

     image_panaroma.Items.Add(pi);
 }
```

xaml layout is :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <controls:Panorama Name="image_panaroma">
    </controls:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Also is there any other way possible to give sliding transition to images?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what exception you get, but I think a better approach would be to create an `ItemTemplate` for the `Panorama` control and bind it to your list of objects.

```
public class ItemData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

...

List<ItemData> items = new List<ItemData>(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    items.Add(new ItemData { Name = "Something", Path = "Image path" });
}

this.image_panorama.ItemsSource = items;
```

Your XAML would look something like this:

```
<controls:Panorama x:Name="image_panorama">
    <controls:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
    <controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Panorama>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to add header in it?..coz i dont want anything as header

Comment: @IndianBird: No, it is not. You can remove `HeaderTemplate` from `XAML`.

Comment: Apologies for the misdirection on the null header. I've removed it from my answer, though I still stand my my approach :)

Answer (score 0):

You say that this only shows 1 image. Is this the same image 10 times (one for each pivotItem) or is only 1 pivotItem being created?

If it's the first then it could be how you're creating the image and/or setting the source.
Your example code doesn't show that you're using a different image source or how `image_new` is scoped. Without a more complete example of your actual code it's hard to say for sure.

The following will (works-on-my-machine) create 10 items all with the same image:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var image_new = new Image();
            var pi = new PanoramaItem();

            var bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Background.png", UriKind.Relative));

            image_new.Source = bi;
            pi.Content = image_new;
            image_panaroma.Items.Add(pi);
        }
    }
```

Are you using the January Update? (I am-see above for WOMM disclaimer) This update includes changes that affect the panorama control.

Comment: Thanx for ur reply...I am getting same image in all 10 items.I can't use January update due to some client requirements.I am also following the same procedure bt no success :(

Comment: Its working this way..but i have another prob: Presently on sliding towards left i see the next image and towards right i see the previous image.Can this behavior be changed like sliding towards left gives previous image and towards right next image?

Comment: @IndianBird no. A panorama is intended for a specific purpose and should exhibit the same functionality in all cases so the user doesn't have to learn how to use it. What are you actually trying to achieve? It sounds like you're just using a Panorama as it's the closest standard control to what you want but you're hitting limitations because it isn't intended to do whatever it is you want it to.

Comment: Actually  wan to give a slide in and slide out transition to images.Is there any other way possible apart from Panorama control?